# getString() always return the default language strings. How to check is the app is looking for the localised string file?

Tags: android, locale, chinese-locale

Based on the Android documentation :

- https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

I have created a ressource file for the zh locale :
[image: screenshot]

And I have started two emulator: one using english as locale, and one using  `zh_TW_#Hant`.

And yet, every strings are in english.

I tried to follow the Android documentation, but it is not working so I assumed my configuration is wrong. I restarted devices, and checked the files many times. What could be wrong ?

**Is there a way to know if the system is looking for the zh ressource and failed to find it, or if it immediately looking for the default one ?**

Edit:
I have tried the following configurations :

- using `values-zh/` instead of `values-b+zh/` for the phone in `zh_TW_#Hant` still loads the default strings.
- all Locales on emulators are changed through the phone settings.
- using `values-es/` and a phone in Spanish works perfectly.
- using `values-zh-TW/` for the phone in `zh_TW_#Hant` works !

So the issue I don't understand is why the Spanish+Region loads the es file, whereas the Chinese+Region does not load the zh file ?

Comment: Try using `values-zh/` instead of `values-b+zh/` and see if you have better luck. You should be able to use `Locale.getDefault()` to see what your process sees as being the requested language.

Comment: In the emulators, I have found that using the "Custom Locale" tool they provide and specifying something with a country code often doesn't work. Going to the regular Android language settings ("Settings -> Language & Input -> Language") and setting it there works in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to the app gradle

```
android {

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about what this is doing and why it may solve the problem?